# Поиск по массиву коллекции

Tags: java, android

Вообщем есть массив, который реализует модель `ArrayList<MyModel>`. Как реализовать по нему поиск?

```
if(MyPlayer.LastPlay.contains(t)==true){ }
```

`t` типа `String`.
Возвращает всегда `false`. Даже если в массиве есть такая строка

Код модели

```
public class ModelMusic
{
    String title;
    String album;
    String src;
    ModelMusic(String t, String a, String s){
        title=t;
        album=a;
        src=s;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public String getAlbum(){
        return album;
    }
    public String getSrc(){
        return src;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, разверните вопрос. Я не думаю, что вас устроит ответ "используйте `list.indexOf`"

Comment: Мне нужно проверить или есть в массиве определённая строка. List.contains(строка) не хочет работать

Comment: Приведите кусок кода, опишите, какие данные вы передаете на вход, что вы ожидаете получить и что вы получаете на самом деле.

Comment: Обновил ответ........................

Comment: Рискну предположить, что либо `LastPlay` содержит не строки, а какие-то другие объекты, либо вы пытаетесь проверить наличие в списке строки, содержащей подстроку `t`. Покажите объявление `MyPlayer.LastPlay`.

Comment: Так, стоп... язык еще уточните.

Comment: Обновил ответ, язык java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List.contains(Object o)` проверяет равенство объекта в списке параметру метода через `o.equals`. Поскольку у вас в списке хранятся другие объекты, `String.equals` никогда не вернет `true`. Поэтому нужно проверять равенство конкретному полю. Для удобства можно завернуть поиск в отдельный метод:

```
private static ModelMusic findSongByTitle(List<ModelMusic> list, String title) {
    for ( ModelMusic song : list ) {
        if ( title.equals( song.getTitle() ) ) {
            return song;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Метод предполагает, что список не содержит `null`, и `title` тоже не `null`.

С использованием `Stream` можно написать еще так:

```
Optional<ModelMusic> r = lastPlay.stream()
    .filter( song -> song.getTitle().equals(t) )
    .findAny();
```